# Flake8のE241が表示されない

Tags: python, python3, vscode

現在VSCodeでPythonのプログラミングに挑戦しており、Flake8をインストールしていますが、E241が表示できません。E501やE401は表示されるのですが、空白を無駄に開けてしまう癖に対応できるE241が表示されなくて困っています。
これはなぜ起きてしまうのでしょうか。

**実行環境:**
Flake8 5.4.1 / 3.6.0
Python 3.8.3

Comment: VSCode関連では無い記事ですが、こんな設定が何処かにあるのでは？ [コーディング規約に準拠する](https://qiita.com/Y_oHr_N/items/e4a1bbf3fd8ae90b4d94#%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E8%A6%8F%E7%B4%84%E3%81%AB%E6%BA%96%E6%8B%A0%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B) VSCodeに関連してそうなのはこちらとの組み合わせでしょうかね。[4. flake8 の設定値を変更する](https://qiita.com/fehde/items/723b619013dc86008acc#4-flake8-%E3%81%AE%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A%E5%80%A4%E3%82%92%E5%A4%89%E6%9B%B4%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B) そして最初の記事の`ignore`も含めた設定をしている例。[VS CodeでPythonのLinterとしてPylintの代わりにflake8を導入するメモ](https://www.keisuke69.net/entry/2021/01/18/135517)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E241 はデフォルトでは無効にされています。その他にもいくつかのルールが、満場一致で受け入れられておらず、PEP 8でも必須とされていないことから、デフィルトでは無効にされています。（参考: [Error codes](https://pycodestyle.pycqa.org/en/latest/intro.html#error-codes)）

[extend-select](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/options.html#cmdoption-flake8-extend-select) に E241 を追加し、有効にするとよいでしょう。

#### 設定ファイルで有効にするには

[Configuration Locations](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/configuration.html#configuration-locations) で説明されている（いずれかの）設定ファイルに以下を追加します。

```ini
[flake8]
extend-select = E241
```

#### コマンドラインオプション で有効にするには

```bash
flake8 --extend-select=E241
```

として実行します。VSCode 上で実行する際のオプションの設定は `Python › Linting: Flake8 Args` です。これに `--extend-select=E241` を追加します。（参考: [Linting Python in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_flake8)）

Comment: ありがとうございます！解決いたしました。